# Whats the smallest possible value off p and q?

Tags: problem-solving

The question is taken from a problem-solving test:

Both p and q are positive integers. What's the smallest possible value of the numbers such that:

$\frac{p}{q}=0,126126\overline{126}$

I don't really know how to proceed with such a question without just trying different values I see if I find some pattern. Does anyone have a method for solving these types of questions in general?

Comment: We may have a language issue here.  Can you confirm that the right hand value of the equation is a repeating decimal less than 0 with the digits 126 repeating?

Comment: If $\frac{p}{q} = 0.126126\dots$, what can you say about $1000p$?

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793967/converting-repeating-decimal-numbers-to-fractions).

Comment: Using the (inftinite) geometric series: $0.\overline{126}=126\cdot \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{10^3}\right)^k=126\cdot \frac{\frac{1}{10^3}}{1-\frac{1}{10^3}}=126\cdot \frac{1}{10^3-1}$. Next you cancel some numbers.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{p}{q}=0.\overline{126}$$
Multiply the equation above by $10^n$ where $n=$the number of repeating digits.
$$1000\frac{p}{q}=126.\overline{126}$$
Subtracting the given equation from the second equation.
$$999\frac{p}{q}=126$$
Solve the equation above for $\frac{p}{q}$.
$$\frac{p}{q}=\frac{126}{999}$$
$$\frac{p}{q}=\frac{14}{111}$$
Therefore, $p=14$ and $q=111$ are the smallest possible integer values for $p$ and $q$.